# Overflow auto not showing scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have a grid parent, with 2 columns. The left child has the same height as the parent (here is 100vh) and the right child is 1000px, which is greater than the parent.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="leftcol"></div>
    <div class="rightcol"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
body{
    background-color: white;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.leftcol {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.rightcol {
    background-color: black;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I only want the right child to be scrollable, since it's height is greater than the parent, the left child will stay still. I've read some other posts and they suggest using **overflow: auto** on the child but mine is not working.

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try it

```
<body>
    <div class="leftcol">
        <p class="top">top</p>
        <p class="bottom">bottom</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcol">
        <p class="top">top</p>
        <p class="bottom">bottom</p>
    </div>
</body>

<style type="text/css">
    body{
        background-color: white;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .leftcol{
        background-color: grey;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 50%;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .rightcol{
        background-color: black;
        height: 1000px;
        width: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .leftcol p,
    .rightcol p {
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .rightcol p.top {
        top: 0;
    }
    .rightcol p.bottom {
        bottom: 0;
        padding-top: 900px;
    }
    .leftcol p.bottom {
        padding-top: 80vh;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You should probably add an explanation to your code

Comment: I understand what you did there and the result works well, but this seems to be another approach and have nothing to do with overflow

Answer (score 0):

You should add inner child to right column, Right column height will be of parent which is 100vh, the inner element will be of 1000px as you mentioned which will cause the parent element `.rightcol` to overflow if the height exceeds max height.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: white;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.leftcol {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.rightcol {
    background-color: black;
    height:100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:20px;
}

.inner-col{
  height: 1000px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="leftcol"></div>
    <div class="rightcol">
      <div class="inner-col"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no scrollbar because you don't need to scroll. If you want to show a scrollbar though, you can replace `overflow: auto;` with `overflow: scroll;`. This makes it show the scrollbar no matter what.

You can learn more about overflows here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Overflowing_content

Comment: "overflow: visible;. This makes it show the scrollbar no matter what."

This is just wrong. This makes content overflow the bounds of the box *without* scrollbars.

Comment: @Mud I mistakenly typed `overflow: visible;` instead of `overflow: scroll;`. Please try that instead.